# Spell check language list is empty in Geary Mail

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, geary

I am using Geary in Gnome in Arch Linux. I cannot get spell check to get in Geary. All I see is an empty list in the spell check window. Evolution also said I don't have a dictionary installed. I wonder what dictionary I should install in order for the spell check to work for these mail clients?

Answer (score 1):

When you write or reply an email, at bottom right you should have a [ab] button.

This is where you can enable a specific spelling corrector.

If nothing is available. You should install some dictionaries.

> **Checking spelling**
>
> Geary supports spell-checking your composed email in one or more
> languages, as you type. To enable spell-checking, first ensure your
> computer has spell-check dictionaries installed for the desired
> languages. Consult your computer's help to determine how to install
> dictionaries if not present.
>
> To select languages for spell-checking, click the Spell check button
> on the formatting toolbar, and the language selection popover will
> appear. Click on a language in the list to toggle it on or off, and
> click the - button to remove it from the list. If a language does not
> appear in the list, search for it by typing its name in the search
> box, then click the + button to add it.

*src: [https://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/help.gnome.org/geary/write.html](https://people.gnome.org/%7Eshaunm/help.gnome.org/geary/write.html)*

On Arch you can install those dictionaries following instructions from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Language_checking

At the time [`hunspell`](https://nuspell.github.io/) package is probably the most popular. Then you may want to install a specific local language from:

- [official repository](https://archlinux.org/packages/?q=hunspell-)
- or [community repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?SeB=n&K=hunspell-)